# video embed tag and JQuery dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mouseevent

I have an object tag holding an embed tag as follows:

```
<object classid="clsid:9BE31822-FDAD-461B-AD51-BE1D1C159921"  width="640" height="360" id="vlc" events="True">
  <param name="MRL" value="" />
  <param name="ShowDisplay" value="True" />
  <param name="AutoLoop" value="False" />
  <param name="AutoPlay" value="False" />
  <param name="Volume" value="50" />
  <param name="toolbar" value="true" />
  <param name="StartTime" value="0" />
  <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
  <EMBED pluginspage="http://www.videolan.org"
    type="application/x-vlc-plugin"
    version="VideoLAN.VLCPlugin.2"
    width="640"
    height="360"
    toolbar="true"
    loop="false"
    text="Waiting for video"
    wmode="transparent"
    name="vlc">
  </EMBED>
</object>
```

And I am trying to get, using JQuery, right mouse click on the video itself and pop up a dialog over the video.

the dialog div element:

```
    <div>
        <input id="dialog" style="position: relative; z-index=10">
    </div>
```

I cannot get it to work.
Any idea how to get it working? what is the JQuery Javascript code for getting the mouse click on the video, it is only working for me on the div "holding" the video?

Comment: And what is the jquery code you tried?

Comment: I tried:      $(document).ready(function(){

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){   $function() {   $("#dialog").dialog({autoopen:false});    $(document).mousedown(function(e){   if(e.button==2){    $("#vlc").contextmenu(function(){   $("#dialog").dialog("open");.................

Comment: Did you try attaching event to object itself?

Comment: Vikram,  yes I did and all I get is the dialog when I am in the chrome debugger. when I am out of the debugger I do not get the dialog.

Comment: Isn't `$(document).ready(function(){ $function() {` unneccessarily redundant?

Comment: SebasSBM, you are correct, but I removed it and same result.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it.
   1. I added to my embed an attribute: windowless="true".
   2. I added a .
   3. Added a style="z-index: -1; position: absolute" to the object "holding" the embed.
   4.Added to my embed allowscriptaccess="always".
   5. Added to my dialog div element style="z-index: 9999; position: relative"

Now it is working fine.